# pass variable to deferred JSON function?

Tags: jquery, getjson, jquery-deferred

How can I use myValue in this deferred function so that myQuery is defined?

```
$.getJSON('lorem.json', function (data) {

    var myKey = $("input").val(); 
    var myValue = data[myKey];

}).then(function () {

    var myQuery = "http://example.com?q=" + myValue ;

    $.getJSON(myQuery, function (info) {
        console.log(info);
...
```

Comment: try to global it, instead of `var myValue = data[myKey];` use `window.myValue = data[myKey];` then use it with your `myQuery` like `var myQuery = "http://example.com?q=" + window.myValue ;`

Comment: Can't you just use one callback function? Why do you need the function split up in two?

Comment: @MaveRick A global variable is overkill and will only cause issues if at some time in another script file you want to use the same global variable for a different purpose. You could move `myValue` to the containing scope of the `$.getJSON` *call*, which would make it accessible to both callback functions. If that containing scope is not the global scope but another function scope, it won't pollute the global scope nor cause naming conflicts. Either way, it seems as though the OP wants to do something much simpler, for which there is probably a much simpler solution.

Comment: how you would make the variable `myValue` readable by second function without making it global var?

Comment: What @MattiasBuelens is saying, and I agree with, is there is no reason to defer the function, the regular callback function on success is enough to handle what the OP is doing in his code example.

Comment: @MaveRick If all of the OP's code is encapsulated inside a function, you could move the `myValue` declaration to that function's scope. Nested functions (such as the callbacks) have access to the variables declared in their parent function's scope (the encapsulating function), allowing those nested functions to access a shared variable *local to that parent function*. [MDN does a great job explaining this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures) (This is getting off-topic though...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parent context

```
var myValue = null;
$.getJSON('lorem.json', function (data) {

    var myKey = $("input").val(); 
    myValue = data[myKey];

}).then(function () {

    var myQuery = "http://example.com?q=" + myValue ;

    $.getJSON(myQuery, function (info) {
        console.log(info);
```

Comment: Making globals isn't good practice.  Wrapping it in a function works, but there is a downside to this approach.  For example, if you are creating a utility function that returns a deferred that goes from data -> info, you can't access that variable without making it globally available.  With a deferred, you can carry that information along and easily pass the callbacks any information you picked up in the steps along the way.

Comment: But the code don't make a var global, only create a var with parent context. Each function will create a self context, to share a data, only is possible in parent context.